# Aplicativo abre e fecha

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin-forms

Depois que atualizei meu celular (ASUS Zenfone 3) para o Android O meus aplicativos abrem e fecham quando tento debugar...
Eu só consigo debugar se eu excluir o app do meu celular e compilar novamente, alguém sabe como corrigir isso? 
É muito chato ter que excluir toda vez antes de testar novamente.

Eu utilizo o Visual Studio 2017.

Comment: Aparece algum erro no logcat?

Comment: Hoje a noite irei dar uma olhada e te respondo @Leonardo

Comment: Acabei tendo tempo de ver só ontem esse projeto, mas no logcat não aparece nada de mais

Comment: Verifique se o seu celular está em modo desenvolvedor e se está habilitado a instalação de fontes desconhecidas

Comment: Meu celular já está em modo desenvolvedor e com as instalações de fontes desconhecidas habilitada

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se desinstalar o aplicativo manualmente resolve o problema, é possível esteja ficando alguma coisa em cache ou com referências corrompidas.

Tenta mudar a configuração de deploy nas propriedades do projeto android para não usar o *fast deployment* ou a *runtime compartilhada*.

[image: Exemplo propriedades projeto android]

*A imagem mostra as configurações marcadas, que é o padrão. Você deve desmarcá-las*

Essas opções vem marcadas por padrão e em alguns casos não funciona bem mesmo.